# Replace a URL on load using only class or url reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some javascript that will find the current URL and set as li to class active. What I then need it to do so that the accordion menu will function correctly is to replace the URL in the associated a href with "#".

ie.

```
<li><a id="Create" href="../Create/Create.html"> Create</a>
```

needs to be changed to:

```
<li><a id="Create" href="#"> Create</a>
```

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li class="">
      <a id="Dashboard" href="../dashboard/dashboard.html"> Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="Create" href="../Create/Create.html"> Create</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="Monster" href="../Monster/Monster.html"> Monster</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a id="Custom" href="../Custom/Custom.html"> Custom</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a id="New" href="../New/New.html"> New</a></li>
            <li><a id="Drafts" href="../Drafts/Drafts.html">> Drafts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And current Javascript that will give the current page a class of "active" on the corresponding "li" tag.

```
var url = window.location;

$('ul.topnav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

This would be easily achieved utilizing the ID:
    document.getElementById("Create").href="#";
but this is not an option due to the magnitude of the site. It needs to be done via javascript.

I've tried to do this with 
    document.getElementByClassName('li.active a').href="#";

but that is not working. I'm also concerned this might strip out all hrefs under that li.

Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Comment: Why not fix it at the server source code? Otherwise filter for `<a>` that have siblings `<ul>`

Comment: do you have notepad ++ ? do a find/replace in all folders within the current directory.

Comment: I've tried:

$( "li.active a:first" ).setAttribute("href", "#");

If I do this with:

$( "li.active a:first" ).css( "background-color", "red" );

And it works fine but not with setAttribute... any ideas?